# How to use a value i get from a form in another php

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['edit_button'])){
    $ID=$_POST['edit_button'];
    $query = "SELECT  PNAME , GENDER, AGE, ADDRESS , PHONENUMBER
    FROM PATIENT LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONENUMBER
    ON PID=EPID AND '$ID'=PID";

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($stid);
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

        $patient_name= $row['PNAME'];
        $patient_gender= $row['GENDER'];
        $patient_address= $row['ADDRESS'];
        $patient_age= $row['AGE'];
        $patient_phone= $row['PHONENUMBER'];
    }
?>


 <?php
if(isset($_POST['Edit_Patient'])){
    $new_pname=$_POST['pName'];
    $new_pGender=$_POST['pGender'];
    $new_pAge=$_POST['pAge'];
    $new_pAddress=$_POST['pAddress'];
    $new_phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $update_query=" UPDATE PATIENT 
                   SET PNAME= '$new_pname', GENDER= '$new_pGender', AGE=$new_pAge, ADDRESS='$new_pAddress'
                   WHERE PID= '$ID'";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $update_query);
    $result=oci_execute($stid);
    if (!$result) {
        echo oci_error();   
    }

}
```

?>

THESE TWO PHPS ARE IN THE PHP FILE registration.php

So, my question is: i get the Id from the first php but i can't use in the second where both are in the same php file.**Also, i tried putting the `$ID=$_POST['edit_button'];` above the if statement, but it gave me an error**

Comment: Put the second block inside the if the first, since it's dependent on the $ID being populated.

Comment: you are trying to use a variable in second step which is local to first step. Change the scope of $ID and you should be through

Comment: But how do i change the scope of id? when i write it above the first if it gave me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign $ID in one hidden field of Update Patient form. So when you submit that form you will get a value of $ID as follows:

Initialize $ID with blank value above the first if statement:

```
$ID = "";
```

Update Patient Form

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
...
</form>
```

Second If statement

```
if(isset($_POST['Edit_Patient'])){
    ...
    $ID = $_POST['patient_id'];
    ...
}
```

Hope this may helpful to anyone!